# Python - Order an array using a specific element

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have this data structure:

```
[{'href': '/elements/folder/107', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'first document'}, {'href': /elements/folder/80', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'second document'}, {'href': '/elements/folder/127', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'third document'}]
```

I need to sort it having in the first place the "greatest" string of 'href'. So the sort should be done using as reference this specific element.
In this case, the desiderd output should be:

```
[{'href': '/elements/folder/127', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'third document'}, {'href': '/elements/folder/107', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'first document'}, {'href': /elements/folder/80', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'second document'} ]
```

Comment: What does 'greatest' mean?

Comment: I need to order it using the last part of the first string (e.g.: 107 of th /elements/folder/107). I though that I consider it as a string so for example '/elements/folder/107' < '/elements/folder/119'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sorted` function. Use a `lambda` expression as the `key`, where you look at the value for the `'href'` key, split on `'/'`, and convert the last element to `int`. Then `reverse` the list so it is in descending order.

```
l = [{'href': '/elements/folder/107', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'first document'},
     {'href': '/elements/folder/80', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'second document'},
     {'href': '/elements/folder/127', 'type': 'document', 'name': 'third document'}]

>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: int(i['href'].split('/')[-1]), reverse=True)
[{'href': '/elements/folder/127', 'name': 'third document', 'type': 'document'},
 {'href': '/elements/folder/107', 'name': 'first document', 'type': 'document'},
 {'href': '/elements/folder/80', 'name': 'second document', 'type': 'document'}]
```